# PL/SQL How to get user input

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to ask the user for input and store the input in the variable. When I run the following, it prompts with "Enter value for v_degree:" and then "Enter value for v_num", when I want it to ask usng the 2 lines I provided: "Enter your input scale (C or F) for temperature:" and "Enter your temperature value to be converted:"

```
DECLARE
    v_degree VARCHAR2(1);
    v_num VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enter your input scale (C or F) for temperature:', &v_degree);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enter your temperature value to be converted:', &v_num);
END;
/
```

Comment: Sqlplus sees &v_degree and &v_num as variables and prompts for their values.

Comment: Also, `dbms_output.put_line` takes one argument, not two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL/SQL is a server-side language, and as such no facilities are provided to interact directly with users. There are a few options:

1. If you're using SQLPlus as a client you can use commands provided by SQLPlus, such as ACCEPT, to obtain user input.
2. Oracle provides the UTL_FILE package which can be used to read data from files, with some limitations.
3. Oracle also provides for "external tables", which is a way to read a file and have it appear as a table in the database.

Best of luck.

Comment: I try using ACCEPT but it says "invalid SQL statement"

Comment: That's correct. ACCEPT is not an SQL statement - it's an SQLPlus command. [See the User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm)

Comment: @bob jarvis it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
v_degree VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT :in_degree;
v_num VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT :in_num;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You entered input scale (C or F) for temperature: '||v_degree);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You entered temperature value to be converted: '||v_num);
END;
```

Good luck